# C++ Code not working If i put zero in Exponent

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void power(void)
{
    int base, exponent=1, result, loopstart=1;
    cout << "enter base: ";
    cin >> base;
    cout << "enter exponent: ";
    cin >> exponent;
    result = base;
    while(loopstart < exponent)
    {
        result = base * result;
        loopstart++;
    }
    cout << "the result is: " << result;
}

int main()
{
    power();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the C++ Code i wrote to find the desired power of a number. If `base = 5` and `exponent = 0`, the function should return `1`, but currently my program is outputting `5`. I'm required to use a `while` loop to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you expect that?  Your program sets `result` to 5, then skips the loop.

Comment: Now is a good time to review this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because your program is only capable of computing powers of 1 or higher.  The initial value before the loop is the base to the power of 1.

```
result = base;
while(loopstart < exponent)
{
    result = base * result;
    loopstart++;
}
```

To improve this, obviously you need to start from the power 0.  That means your loop needs to perform one extra step for the remaining powers, which you can achieve by initializing `loopstart` to 0.

```
loopstart = 0;
result = 1;
while(loopstart < exponent)
{
    result = base * result;
    loopstart++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void power(void)
{
int base,exponent=1,result,loopstart=1;
cout<<"enter base: ";
cin>>base;
cout<<"enter exponent: ";
cin>>exponent;
result=base;
if (exponent == 0){
    result = 0;
    }
else{
while(loopstart<exponent)
{
    result=base*result;
    loopstart++;
}
}
cout<<"the result is: "<<result;
}
int main()
{
power();

return 0;
}
```

The issue is that before you even run the while loop, you've set the result to be the base. So even if the while loop doesn't run, the result will always be the base, as you have it. Try adding the if statement as I have above.

Comment: But the Assignment i have got , it has to be done via while only, Is this even possible in while or not?